# Packaging Office apps for SCCM 2012

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, sccm-2012

How can I package office 2010 applications individually for distribution via SCCM 2012?

I can package the office suite with no problem using an MSP file to customize it, but if I install only Excel for example using setup.exe /adminfile excelonly.msp, I can not later run the install again with a different MSP file to add Word to the existing installation.

Error I get is:

The /adminfile command-line option can be used only during initial installation of the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the individual applications in the Office Suite as individual application installs thus use those to package them individually.

Comment: Yep that does it. Silly miscommunication on our part - I thought they downloaded the individual installs...